# How do you plot this particular function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to draw these two function in Matlab

g(x) = sin(x)/(1+x^2) and
f(x) = (x^2)/(2-x)

However I am struggling with it, here is my code

```
x=linspace(-5,5); 
y1= sin(x)/(1+x^2);
y2= x^2/(2-x);
plot(x,y1,x,y2)
```

Every time I try to run an empty figure is displayed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you run your code, you'll realize that you are getting the following error:

> Error using `^`
>   Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
>   To compute elementwise `POWER`, use `POWER` (`.^`) instead.

As the message very clearly states, you need to use [`power`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) (`.^`) to perform the element-wise operation rather than [`mpower`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html) (`^`). Additionally, you'll want to use [`rdivide`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) (`./`) rather than [`mrdivide`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) (`/`) to perform element-wise division.

```
y1 = sin(x) ./ (1+x.^2);
y2 = x.^2 ./ (2-x);
```

[image]

If you want each plot to be on it's own scale, you can use [`yyaxis`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html)

```
yyaxis left
plot(x, y1)
yyaxis right
plot(x, y2);
```

[image]

Comment: I wish I could upvote both your answer and your edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Suever, but another problem arised. How do you refine the graph of f(x), which is y2. Because it looks like a straight line and it isnt.

Comment: @FaisalBinMahfoodh You probably need to add some parentheses to get the correct order of operations

Comment: Can you elaborate more please? Because I'm new to programming.

Comment: @FaisalBinMahfoodh I have no clue what function you're trying to plot. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html) for a list of operator precedence

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! And the functions that I am trying to plot is shown above.

Comment: @FaisalBinMahfoodh The functions are completely different scales so of course the one is going to look flat

Comment: Yeah I saw it, thank you a lot. Also, I found out that fplot is a much more better function than plot in drawing functions.

Comment: @FaisalBinMahfoodh If this worked for you please consider marking it as a solution using the checkmark to the left of the answer